# Tile objects in a Grid AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, grid, air, tile

I want to put an array of objects into a grid. I know the code is simple but somehow I'm not getting what I want.

Code:

```
const PADDING:Number = 10:

const COL:Number = Math.floor(Math.sqrt(tiles.length);
const ROW:Number = Math.floor(Math.sqrt(tiles.length);

for(var i:int = 0; i< COL; i++)
{
  var tile:TileSprite = tiles[i];
  tile.x = i * tile.width + PADDING;

  for(var j:int = 0; j < ROW; j++)
  {
     tile.y = j * tile.height + PADDING;
  }
}
```

Notes:

- The array is declared else where as a public variable

- This is to be part of a game engine I'm building so I want it as flexible as possible

- The tiles as reading their properties for an XML file. But I don't want to use the XML to hard code the tiles' positions.

Thanks in advance for your help. Let me know if you need any more clarification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest looking into the modulus operator rather than nesting loops.

This blog post outlines how to do just that:

http://www.davidpett.com/actionscript-3-dynamic-rows-and-columns/

Using David's example as a starting point, your code would then look like this:

```
var COLUMNS:int = int(Math.sqrt(tiles.length));
var PADDING:Number = 10;

for(var i:int; i < tiles.length; i++)
{
    var tile:TileSprite = tiles[i];
    tile.x = (i % COLUMNS) * (tile.width + PADDING);
    tile.y = int(i / COLUMNS) * (tile.height + PADDING);
}
```

Comment: instead of using `Math.floor`, just cast it as it's faster. e.g. `var COLUMNS:int = int(Math.sqrt(tiles.length));`

Comment: also, i'd keep a `COLUMNS` or `ROWS` variable as well (in the XML) as in your current example it only allows for square maps, which isn't very flexible :) e.g. `var COLUMNS:int = int(tiles.length/ROWS);`

Comment: Good call on both accounts. Updating example.

Comment: In the name of simplicity, I'm just updating the example to use casting since the rest solves the OP's original problem. But I do agree that keeping the column count external via XML makes better architectural sense.